# Safari search google directly on right click highlighted link text

Tags: safari, search, contextual-menu

I am using Safari 11 on macOS 10.13.

Just wondering why right clicking the link text would make "Search with Google" moved to "Services"?

Thanks.

**Normal Search with Google:**
[image: Normal Search with Google]
**More steps for a Google search:**
[image: More steps for a Google serach]

Answer (score 1):

It's all about the definition of service, by the way also in the 'normal search' you can find 'Search with google' also under the services, is repeated